Цикл for в цикле for - liquid/jekyll
В чем суть: на главной есть блок который должен выводить 3 последние новые статьи из раздела (и его категорий).
Чтобы это реализовать, при создании поста в 'categories' прописываю название категории, пример: [ovoshi].
Далее, создал yaml файл со списком разделов и его подкатегорий.

Итак, у каждой статьи прописано по 1 категории. Нужно, чтобы в блоке выводились три последние материала из раздела овощные культуры в независимости от прописанной категории, но в пределах этого раздела.
Написал следующий код ↓
{%- assign category_names = site.data.list_of_sections_with_categories.yagodnye-kultury -%}
{%- for post in site.posts **limit: 3** %}
{%- for list_of_categories in category_names -%}
{%- if post.categories contains list_of_categories -%}
{%- include /second-section-item-1-test.html -%}
{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}{% endfor %}

Всё работало до того момента, пока не прописал ограничение на вывод 'limit: 3' (выделено жирным в коде). Когда прописан этот ограничитель, он показывает 2 материала. Например чтобы показать 6 статей, в лимит нужно прописать цифру > 10.
Как это можно исправить или может быть есть другой обходной путь?
